# How to creat a feature type using rest/ php on geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, php, geoserver-rest-api

I'm trying to create a feature type for a ship in geoserver but when I post the request to the server I get this response:

```
[geoserver.rest] - Trying to create new feature type inside the store, but no attributes were specified
```

This is xml data that I'm sending to the server :

```xml
<featureType>
        <name>'.$layerName.'</name>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <srs>RGF93_Lambert_93</srs>
        <projectionPolicy>FORCE_DECLARED</projectionPolicy>
        <nativeName>'.$layerName.'</nativeName>
        <description>'.htmlentities($description, ENT_COMPAT).'</description>
        <store class="dataStore"><name>'.htmlentities($datastoreName, ENT_COMPAT).'</name></store>
</featureType>'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working now, this is my solution:

I created manually a feature type in geoserver then I pickup the generated xml file and adapted to my script

```xml
<featureType>
        <name>ile-de-france</name>
        <type>VECTOR</type>
        <defaultStyle>
            <name>polygon</name>
            <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/styles/polygon.xml" type="application/xml"/>
        </defaultStyle>
        <resource class="featureType">
            <name>'.htmlentities($layerName, ENT_COMPAT).'</name>
            <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/ws_test/datastores/'.htmlentities($datastoreName, ENT_COMPAT).'/featuretypes/'.htmlentities($layerName, ENT_COMPAT).'.xml" type="application/xml"/>
        </resource>
        <attribution>
            <logoWidth>0</logoWidth>
            <logoHeight>0</logoHeight>
        </attribution>
    </featureType>
```

Hope that can help someone :) cheers